# reading crx data in a cq5 service

Tags: sql, aem

From following link [querying](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html)

I found that, there are different ways, JCR Query manager, xpath, SQL-2 to do the query against content.

I would like to know, what is the best approach and any examples.

What I am trying to do is , **Create a service, read all the child pages content** below `http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/en/products.html` and `http://localhost:4502/damadmin#/content/dam/geometrixx/documents`

send the specific information of these child pages to front end.

Thank you,
Sri

Comment: If you just want to read child pages, I wouldn't use a query at all and just traverse the tree. listChildren() on Page returns you an Iterator<Page>

Answer (score 0):

I created a post a while back comparing the APIs for querying:

http://itgumby.github.io/blog/2014/cq-queries-demystified.html

- javax.jcr.query vs com.day.cq.search
- javax.jcr.query syntaxes: SQL2 vs XPath vs JQOM
- search API vs the REST-ful interface at /bin/querybuilder.json
- generally has examples for each
- pay attention to the NodeTypes - if you just want `cq:Page, cq:PageContent or nt:unstructured`

I hope that helps you.